# Odoo how to update or install modules for multiple databases at once

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

Folks,

How to update or install modules for multiple databases at once ?

I've tried to run odoo with comma-separated list of DBs as below,

```
odoo-bin --config=/etc/odoo.conf  --database local1,local2 --update all
```

but it applied upgrade on the first database only (local1) and ignored the second !!!

Any ideas !

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I think you could write your own script to update each database. you could try the following:

```sh
odoo-bin --config=/etc/odoo.conf  --database local1 --update all --stop-after-init
odoo-bin --config=/etc/odoo.conf  --database local2 --update all --stop-after-init
```

you could check all the available Odoo Cli from the source code:

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/tools/config.py#L104

Comment: you rock ! However I run it as `odoo --config /etc/odoo/odoo.conf --database second --update all & sleep 120 && exit 0"` and it works but your solution is absolutely better one. Thanks !

Comment: I wonder how this parameter doesn't listed here https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/reference/cmdline.html

Comment: they may forgot to add it.